# Get the row and filename where the first position and last position has a value with grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'd like to know how to find a value (in Unix using grep) in files that the first position of the row start with 0 (position 1), and in the position 34 (last position) has 2.

Eg.

```
0000014081472505        00267522
2100010000HCGH09730ASCTBBEONTVA0
10000430030307134 EUR0BE       5
2300010000BE81000090765324     9
```

The result will be

```
0000014081472505        00267523
```

I'm not expert using regular expression.

Comment: I guess you have a type in the desired result. It should be `...22` instead of `...23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size doesn't matter (xD):

```
$ grep "^0.*2$" file
0000014081472505        00267522
```

If you want to indicate the size:

```
$ grep -E "^0.{30}2$" file
0000014081472505        00267522
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v FS= '$1==0 && $32==2' file
0000014081472505        00267522
```